# OpenYouTubePlayerActivity not working android

Tags: android

I am using `OpenYouTubePlayerActivity.class`

When i write this `intent` into my `activity`

```
startActivity(new Intent(null, Uri.parse("ytv:NG3WygJmiVs"),   this,OpenYouTubePlayerActivity.class));
```

I got the following **error** in my `Class`:

```
The constructor Intent(null, Uri, new View.OnClickListener(){}, Class<OpenYouTubePlayerActivity>) is 
 undefined
```

any idea.

Answer (score 0):

I think u can change the way u start the activity.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setData(Uri.parse("ytv:NG3WygJmiVs"));
startActivity(context,OpenYouTubePlayerActivity.class);
```

You are using a "this" within an listener, hence u face this issue.